# OAuth Implementation for JS based frontend application

Tags: javascript, security, oauth

So, I was looking at building a JS based front-end (probably with Vue.js) when I encountered a problem.

The backend already has OAuth based APIs, where I would need to authenticate all the API calls using an access token. So I went looking for ways to do so and found out that I should use [Client Credentials grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4).

The problem is that a frontend application would expose the client ID and secret. These can simply be tracked through the "Network" tab of the Browser's inspector. This makes it possible for anyone to obtain an access token and make dangerous API calls (like **deleting** stuff).

I also found that PKCE flows dont use client secrets.
However, I have 2 problems with PKCE as well:

1. Authorization is not needed for these APIs to call as these are very *adminy* (like user management) APIs.
2. PKCE will also expose the client ID.

Assuming that my understanding is correct, how should I implement the OAuth APIs such that it is secure and does not expose any credentials?

Also, if there needs to be more information, please let me know.

Comment: it's not possible to make calls from the client to the server and at the same time to have a secure token which does not get exposed

Comment: Are there any other secure methods which I can use?